# A non-recoverable sign in failure occurred Google Sigin

Tags: react-native, google-signin, google-console-developer

I'm trying to use [react-native-google-signin](https://github.com/react-native-community/google-signin) in a new project. I'm trying by hours, to solve this issue and I see all topics, threads and issues about it and nothing solve my problem. The error is: `A non-recoverable sign in failure occurred`

- I, created the project in Google Console
- I created the consent screen (and interestingly its status is "not published", would that be the error?)
- I created the OAuth Android Client Id and passed it to the module like this (I've tried to create a webclient id, I've tried it through firebase, none of the alternatives worked):

  GoogleSignin.configure ({
       webClientId: GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
       offlineAccess: false,
     });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the error, something very simple that went unnoticed. The name of the application package is not the same as what I had informed for Google Console / Firebase, so it was enough to change the name and it worked.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you follow the main steps for the Google sign-in integration:

[Google Sign-in integration](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating)

Please put special focus on the configuration for the Google Api Console Project. You must provide the `SHA-1 hash of your signing certificate`.

In case you have some doubt about your hash:

1. For debug hash check in your `android/app/build.gradle`. 
   This is the default signing configuration for debug

```
signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
    }
```

You can retrieve the the SHA1 hash with this command.
I'm asumming you're in the path of your debug.keystore file. (default android/app/debug.keystore)

`keytool -list -v -keystore debug.keystore`

password: `android`

Copy the SHA1 value from the terminal and include in the Console configuration `XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX`

2. For `release` hash you should create your own production keystore and get the SHA1 hash to include in your Console configuration.

Here is some information about retrieve the hash
[Authenticating Your Client](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth)

Here is some information to generate your own keystore
[App Signing](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing?hl=el)

Comment: - I followed the Google configuration steps for android
- Redid the process of creating an oauth client with the correct SHA1
- I redid the process of getting the client id and going to the library
- I ran, and again I came across the same error

Comment: Please post your current code of the initialization. (Do not show your keys)

Comment: The whole code: https://gist.github.com/ThallyssonKlein/2a6b5d8c4554c191d6f4b62dff0b5693

Comment: Be sure to provide the correct webClientId. If you open the google-services.json is the one with this format `{ "client_id": "xxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com", "client_type": 3}`

Comment: The correct json is downloaded from here: https://i.imgur.com/VEvAex5.png right?

Comment: I did a test now. I created a firebase project for the Google Console project, created an android app within the firebase project, added the same SHA1 and then tried it with the client id that came on google-services.json in the same way you showed it. The same mistake happened.

Comment: Check this`https://github.com/react-native-community/google-signin/issues/659. Some people was getting the error because the support email was missing.

Comment: Yes, your answer helps me fix this problem. tks <3

Comment: For me, goodle sign is working in debug but it is not working for release. We have followed all steps. so far no luck